TensorFlow2 function tracing is expensive - System freezes
I am using TensorFlow 2.16 and Python3 for implementing an AutoEncoder and Self-Organizing Map for MNIST dataset. The entire code can be referred to here. For brevity, the main code is:
# SOM hyper-params-
map_height = 10
map_width = 10

gamma = 0.001

# Total number of train steps/iterations-
total_iterations = len(train_dataset) * num_epochs

# Temperature hyper-parm controlling radius of Gaussian neighborhood-
Tmax = 10.0
Tmin = 0.1


class DESOM(Model):
    def __init__(
        self, map_height = 10,
        map_width = 10, latent_dim = 50,
        encoder_dims = [1, 500, 500, 100]
        ):
        super(DESOM, self).__init__()
        self.map_height = map_height
        self.map_width = map_width
        self.map_size = (self.map_height, self.map_width)
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.n_prototypes = self.map_size[0] * self.map_size[1]
        self.encoder_dims = encoder_dims
        self.encoder_dims.append(self.latent_dim)

        self.autoencoder, self.encoder, self.decoder = mlp_autoencoder(
            # encoder_dims = [X_train.shape[-1], 500, 500, 2000, latent_dim],
            encoder_dims = self.encoder_dims,
            act = 'relu', init = 'glorot_uniform',
            batchnorm = False
        )

        # Initialize SOM layer-
        self.som_layer = SOMLayer(
            map_size = (self.map_height, self.map_width), name = 'SOM'
        )(self.encoder.output)

        # Create DESOM model
        self.model = Model(
            inputs = self.autoencoder.input,
            outputs = [self.autoencoder.output, self.som_layer]
        )


    def compile(self, gamma:float = 0.001, optimizer:str = 'adam') -> None:
        """
        Compile DESOM model

        Parameters
        ----------
        gamma : float
            coefficient of SOM loss (hyperparameter)
        optimizer : str (default='adam')
            optimization algorithm
        """
        self.model.compile(
            loss = {'decoder_0': 'mse', 'SOM': som_loss},
            # loss_weights = [1, gamma],
            loss_weights = {'decoder_0': 1.0, 'SOM': gamma},
            optimizer = optimizer
        )

        return None


    def predict(self, x):
        """
        Predict best-matching unit using the output of SOM layer

        Parameters
        ----------
        x : array, shape = [n_samples, input_dim] or [n_samples, height, width, channels]
            input samples

        Returns
        -------
        y_pred : array, shape = [n_samples]
            index of the best-matching unit
        """
        _, d = self.model.predict(x, verbose = 0)
        return d.argmin(axis = 1)


    def map_dist(self, y_pred):
        """
        Calculate pairwise Manhattan distances between cluster assignments and map prototypes
        (rectangular grid topology)

        Parameters
        ----------
        y_pred : array, shape = [n_samples]
            cluster assignments

        Returns
        -------
        d : array, shape = [n_samples, n_prototypes]
            pairwise distance matrix on the map
        """
        
        # y_pred = tf.argmin(input = pairwise_squared_l2dist, axis = 1)
        labels = tf.range(self.n_prototypes)
        tmp = tf.cast(
            x = tf.expand_dims(input = y_pred, axis = 1),
            dtype = tf.dtypes.int32
        )
        # print(labels.dtype, tmp.dtype, y_pred.dtype)
        d_row = tf.abs(tmp - labels) // self.map_size[1]
        d_col = tf.abs(tmp % self.map_size[1] - labels % self.map_size[1])

        # (d_row + d_col).dtype
        # tf.int32

        d_row = tf.cast(x = d_row, dtype = tf.dtypes.float32)
        d_col = tf.cast(x = d_col, dtype = tf.dtypes.float32)

        return d_row + d_col


    def neighborhood_function(
        self, d,
        T, neighborhood = 'gaussian'
    ):
        """
        SOM neighborhood function (Gaussian neighborhood)

        Parameters
        ----------
        d : int
            distance on the map
        T : float
            temperature parameter (neighborhood radius)
        neighborhood : str
            type of neighborhood function ('gaussian' or 'window')

        Returns
        -------
        w : float in [0, 1]
            neighborhood weights
        """
        if neighborhood == 'gaussian':
            # return np.exp(-(d ** 2) / (T ** 2))
            return tf.exp(-tf.square(d) / tf.square(T))
        elif neighborhood == 'window':
            # return (d <= T).astype(np.float32)
            return tf.cast(x = (d <= T), dtype = tf.dtypes.float32)
        else:
            raise ValueError('invalid neighborhood function')


# Initialize MLP AutoEncoder DESOM model-
model = DESOM(
    map_height = map_height, map_width = map_width,
    latent_dim = latent_dim,
    encoder_dims = [784, 500, 500, 100]
)

# Compile model-
model.compile(gamma = gamma, optimizer = 'adam')

# Required for computing temperature for current train step-
# curr_iter = 1
curr_iter = tf.constant(1)
total_iterations = tf.cast(x = total_iterations, dtype = tf.dtypes.int32)

# Train loss-
train_loss = list()


for epoch in range(1, num_epochs + 1):
    for x, _ in train_dataset:

        # Compute bmu/cluster assignments for batch-
        # _, d = model.model.predict(x)
        _, d = model.model(x)
        # y_pred = d.argmin(axis = 1)
        y_pred = tf.argmin(input = d, axis = 1)
        y_pred = tf.cast(x = y_pred, dtype = tf.dtypes.float32)

        # y_pred.shape, d.shape
        # ((1024,), (1024, 100))

        # Compute temperature for current train step-
        curr_T = tf.cast(
            x = Tmax * tf.pow((Tmin / Tmax), (curr_iter / total_iterations)),
            dtype = tf.dtypes.float32
            )

        # Compute topographic (neighborhood) weights for this batch-
        w_batch = model.neighborhood_function(
            d = model.map_dist(y_pred = y_pred),
            T = curr_T, neighborhood = 'gaussian'
        )

        # Train on batch-
        loss = model.model.train_on_batch(x = x, y = [x, w_batch])
        train_loss.append(loss.item())

        curr_iter += 1

It gives me the Warning:

WARNING:tensorflow:5 out of the last 5 calls to <function
TensorFlowTrainer.make_train_function..one_step_on_iterator at
0x7ff0debb1c10> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive
and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating
@tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different
shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please
define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function
has reduce_retracing=True option that can avoid unnecessary retracing.
For (3), please refer to
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more
details.

